# How to assign a prop value to a two state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have searched for this text but none fixed my situation. my condition is I have one prop value I need to set this value to 2 state variable.one is direct assignment one is indirect. now due to async nature of set state or unknown reason before setting that value child got rendered. now how should I control this behavior?
this is my `componentWillReceiveprops` of child

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let lastManualFlag =[...this.state.lastManualFlag];
    console.log('before',lastManualFlag,nextProps.groupBy.length);
    for(var i=0;i<nextProps.groupBy.length;i++){
      lastManualFlag[i]=false;
    }
    console.log("after",lastManualFlag)
    this.setState({lasManualProg:lastManualFlag});
    this.setState({ groupBy: nextProps.groupBy});

  }
```

this is my render method

```
render() {
    console.log('this.state',this.state);
    if (!this.props.groupBy) return null;
```

when I saw console my lastManualFlag is still size 0 array

Comment: Have you tried using only one setState line instead of two?

Comment: sorry it's stupid mistake I have did. `lasManualProg` instead of `lastManualProg`

Comment: There's a typo on it too. `lastManualProg` instead of `lasManualProg`

Answer (score 0):

You have two calls to set state

how about do it in one call like:

```
 this.setState({...state,lastManualProg:lastManualFlag,groupBy: nextProps.groupBy});
```